# Remote clients can't access Delphi WebService hosted in IIS 7.5

Tags: web-services, delphi, windows-7, iis-7.5

### Remote clients can't access Delphi WebService hosted in IIS 7.5

Delphi WS clients are configured to point to URL of Delphi SOAP webService hosted on Windows 7, IIS 7.5 server.

**All clients point to same URL - (not the default 'local host' generated by WSDL
import utility). WebService VD is configured to allow anonymous access using credentials of a
domain admin account**

Problem: clients deployed on the server machine itself run fine, clients deployed on other machines on the network cannot access webService - error msg: 'EDOMParseError at $00534E53 XML document must have a top level element'. I've tried this instantiating the client proxy class with both SOAP and WSDL params.

Same webService hosted on XP-IIS 5 server is accessible to all clients, so I believe this is probably  a configuration problem in IIS 7.5.

Comment: Removed some of your bold formatting, because shouting is not a good way to get attention on SO.

Comment: I'd first check the Windows 7 firewall, make sure it allows incoming connections. Then I'd check IIS's logs to see if anything pops up. This is not really programming related, is it?

Comment: Cosmin you were correct - it was Windows Firewall - allowed file sharing on domain but not other services. Post as answer so you'll get points.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

@CosminPrund was correct in his comment on the question. Windows Firewall was only permitting file sharing in the domain, but not other services.

Answer (score 2):

Check the response document (either by modifying the client or by using a HTTP proxy like [Fiddler](http://www.fiddler2.com/fiddler2/)) - I guess that the malformed document body contains useful information like a server error message.

Comment: mjn - it's not done on the client, it's done on the server. Anonymous access user runs with credentials configured through the authentication snap-in in IIS - by default it runs as a guest but you can set it to any local or domain account you like. In prod scenarios you generally set up a custom account that can access what the WS requires and nothing else. Never set anonymous access to run under a domain admin account on a prod and/or public WebServer!